# Modify chef role attributes from jenkins

Tags: jenkins, chef-infra, knife

I would like to update a chef role attribute from Jenkins.

The knife command:
Knife role edit role-name

Appears to open a text file from a defined editor where changes can be made and then saved. This doesn’t seem like a feasible solution from Jenkins.  Are there any options for achieving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your responses. The solution I went with was to call

```
knife role show role-name
```

persist the output and update the attributes I wanted to modify using jq. Then, update the role using the updated json using

```
knife role from file FILE
```

I hope this help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can manage your roles using "role cookbooks" and then manage the role attributes using the recipe therein from jenkins. Refer to [this](https://www.frankmitchell.org/2014/07/chef-roles/) link for "role cookbooks"

Answer (score 0):

i strongly advise you not to let the build server (jenkins in your case) to push any changes to the repository. the repository is a source of truth, don't let any automation break\modify it.

to my understanding, it feels like there is some other pretty solution.
note that, chef-client has support for in-line attributes ([`--json-attributes`](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html)), which you can utilize to override an attribute and make decisions in your recipe based on the value of that attribute.